# AAR файл не генерируется

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aar

У меня есть проект и lib module (проект это по сути оболочка для lib module, чтоб создать .aar). Ожидается, что он будет работать так: после build project, lib module должен построиться, и сгенерировать `.aar` в папке `build-> output`, который уже можно будет использовать где нужно. Но проблема в том, что он не создается.

Нужно сказать, что на в проекте есть 2 lib module, и второй файл .aar lib-module каждый раз успешно генерируется, то есть очевидно, что-то не так с первым модулем lib где `.aar` не создается.

Я пробовал clean, rebuild, invalidate и все эти вещи, но это не работает.

Есть предположения в чем может быть проблема?

Есть ли возможность (может логами) проверить где студия пробует создать `.aar`? или как поменять куда сохранить файл? или просто посмотреть какуе то инфу по его созданию?

**UPD**

градл файл этого модуля который не генерируется

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.myproject.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("maven-publish")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
}

var frameworkName = "myframeworkname"
group = "here.my.library"
version = "0.0.2"

kotlin {
    android()

    ios {
        compilations.forEach {
            it.kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += arrayOf("-linker-options", "-application_extension")
        }
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "mybasename"
                embedBitcode("disable")
            }
        }
    }

    tvos {
        compilations.forEach {
            it.kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += arrayOf("-linker-options", "-application_extension")
        }
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "mybasename"
                embedBitcode("bitcode")
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
            }
        }

        val iosMain by getting

        val tvosMain by getting {
            dependsOn(iosMain)
        }

        val iosTest by getting

        val tvosTest by getting

        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
    }
    
    android {
        publishLibraryVariants("release", "debug")
    }

    configure(listOf(targets["metadata"], android())) {
        mavenPublication {
            val targetPublication = this@mavenPublication
            tasks.withType<AbstractPublishToMaven>()
                .matching { it.publication == targetPublication }
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 30
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 30
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    println("Project dir : ${projectDir.name}")
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("lib") {
            groupId = "entpay.shared.library"
            artifactId = project.name
            version = project.version as String?
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${projectDir.name}-release.aar")
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    val xcodeMode = if (System.getenv("CONFIGURATION").equals("release", true)) "RELEASE" else "DEBUG"
    val frameworksDirectory = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    val target = System.getProperty("TARGET_PLATFORM") ?: "iosX64"
    println("target = ${target}")
    println("configuration = ${xcodeMode}")
    group = "build"
    inputs.property("mode", xcodeMode)
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(target).binaries.getFramework(xcodeMode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    val path = File(frameworksDirectory,target)
    into(path)
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

Comment: А что е вас в плагинах этого модуля числится?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja добавил градл файл этого модуля в вопрос

Comment: В комбинации с multiplatform даже и не знаю что сказать. Полистайте тут: https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/525231/what-s-the-best-way-to-generate-an-aar-file-from-a-multiplat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге мне помог этот ответ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20927125/5709159, а именно эта команда через терминал - `/gradlew assembleRelease` (или `/gradlew assembleDebug`)